# get the ID of specific row in JQuery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, datatables

I have JQuery table like following image

[image]

I want to alert the `ProductID` once I click `V` link text in Action column

```
    <table id="productTable">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ProductID</th>
                <th>TitleEN</th>
                <th>TypeEN</th>
                <th>ModifiedDate</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

    </table>  


    @* Load datatable css *@
    <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@section Scripts{
    @* Load DataTable js here *@
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#productTable").DataTable({
                        "info": false,
                        "processing": true, 
                        "serverSide": true, 
                        "filter": false, 
                        "orderMulti": false, 
                        "ajax": {
                            "url": "/Home/LoadProductData",
                            "type": "POST",
                            "datatype": "json"
                        },
                        "columns": [
                                { "data": "Product_ID", "name": "Product_ID", "autoWidth": true },
                                { "data": "Product_Title_EN", "name": "Product_Title_EN", "autoWidth": true },
                                { "data": "Product_Type_EN", "name": "Product_Type_EN", "autoWidth": true },
                                { "data": "ModifiedDate", "name": "ModifiedDate", "autoWidth": true },
                                {
                                   data: null,
                                   className: "center",
                                   defaultContent: '<a href="" class="editor_view"> V </a>'
                                }
                                  ]
                    });
                });

                $('#editor_view').on('click', 'a.editor_view', function (e) {

                    alert($("data-Product_ID").val());

                });

    </script>
```

}

currently I alerted its like this

```
alert($("data-Product_ID").val());
```

but it cant get the ID of that, hw can I do this ?

this is the html for table row

```
<tr class="even" role="row">
<td class="sorting_1">02</td>
<td>Current Accounts</td>
<td>Assets</td>
<td></td>
<td class=" center">
<a class="editor_view" href="#"> V </a>
</td>
```

Comment: $(this).closest('tr').find("#data-product_ID").val()

Comment: Cant be sure without seeing the actual html for a typical row, but `$(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).text();` should get it

Comment: @MayankVadiya Its not working just refreshing the page

Comment: Note also it needs to be `$('.editor_view').click(function() { ... }`

Comment: Did you also change the selector as per my last comment. And if that's not working, you need to show the actual html that is being generated for a row (also it should be `<a href="#" ....>`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yep after I changed you said its not working. this is the 
`<td class=" center">
<a class="editor_view" href="#"> V </a></td>`

Comment: You need to edit your question and show the actual html your generating for a typical row (i.e the `<tr>` element and everything inside it

Comment: let me know if this code is online.

Comment: @StephenMuecke this is the all HTML I have , I cannot understand what you said ?

Comment: i have done similar things ,  what i am doing is i am opening a modal popup. i can help you if you can show me your HTML of the table after it render.

Comment: Also your dynamically loading the rows using ajax, so the selector would then need to be `$("#productTable").on('click', '.editor_view', function() { ...`

Comment: Right click on one of the rows you have generated and click `Insect` and then copy the html for the row.

Comment: @StephenMuecke updated

Comment: @PunitGajjar updated my question ,is this enough ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your script to

```
$("#productTable").on('click', '.editor_view', function() {
    var ID = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).text();
    alert(ID);
});
```

Note that your dynamically generating the table rows so you need event delegation attached to an element that exists in the DOM when the view is first generated (i.e the element with `id="productTable"`).

Comment: Opps , anyone said to you before, you're a rock-star :)

Comment: why can't I alert it directly like `alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).text());` ??

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#editor_view').on('click', 'a.editor_view', function (e) {
   alert($("data-Product_ID").val());
});
```

Here you have used "editor_view" as ID and I can view it is set as a class, so it will not work. It should be like

```
$('.editor_view').on('click', 'a.editor_view', function (e) {
  alert($("data-Product_ID").val());
});
```

Comment: please post your table html

Answer (score 0):

Below is my Data table.

```
table_low_stocks.dataTable({
            "bLengthChange": true,
            "processing": false,
           // "serverSide": true,
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bInfo": false,
            "iDisplayLength" : 5,
            "bSort" : true,
            "ajax": {
                'type': 'POST',
                'url': "<?=action('AdvertiserproductsController@postLowstockproducts')?>"
            },
"columns": [
                /* {"data": "sr_no"}, */
                {"data": "product_name"},
                {"data": "inventory"},
                {"data": "update"} 
            ] // set first column as a default sort by asc
        });
```

This is how i am rendering the HTML (Datatable from Controller )

```
return Datatables::of($data)
                        ->add_column('action','<a data-productid="{{$sr_no}}" class="label label-sm label-messages-btn update-product"> <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Update Stock </a>')
                        ->make(true);
```

If you have seen above  i have given data-productid="{{$sr_no}}"  to a tag

so ultimately that is what you have to give anyhow,.

Now from the jquery part.what  have done is .

```
$(document).on("click",".update-product", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();


                var getProductId = $(this).data("productid");
                alert(getProductId);
        });
```

and i got the product Id  :-)

to give data attribute do like

```
data-productid="{{$sr_no}}"
```

and to get the data attribute u have to use

```
$(selector).data("productid");
```

Hope this is helpfull to you.